# Pure-FTPD parallel upload issue

Tags: php, mysql, apache-http-server, whm

i am copying approx 300 10MB files from another server to my server. everything works just fine  but i tried to run parallel thread so that i can complete it fast i got surprised as another file will only uploaded when first upload will free the route of upload.

i opened 5 pages in mozilla browser in new tab and all 5 tab has taken new file name from those 300 file name and i clicked on submit and it was showing submitted but the file will get uploaded only when one file completes and redirect to success page then the uploading of second file will start.
i tried to increase the various settings in whm like max file upload size,  in php configuration editor changed the size as well but nothing worked. then i changed the various settings in Pure-FTPD. as i am uploading files using php file upload i think pure ftp will be used and changed the configuration to this 
then also no success.

```
   Allow Anonymous Uploads              no

   Maximum Connections                 150

    Maximum Connections Per IP Address    20
```

any guide??
i tried changing several mysql parameters also but i am really not able to upload more tha

Comment: What is your programming-related issue? What is `whm`? How is it related to PHP?

Comment: php file upload? if you're using php file uploads, then that's NOT ftp. you're probably running into locked session issues, causing each file upload to run serially, instead of in parallel.

Comment: Perhaps you could post some code?

Comment: @MarcB i think you have pointed out correctly . how to sort out that issue if it is being locked

Comment: @Sammitch its simple file copy script in php

Comment: @wayenjoy oh gee-wiz, that's some super-helpful information, champ. Let me just fire up the ol' telepathy so I can find the problem in your code.

Comment: @Sammitch marcb has correctly pointed out the issue i think.its locked sesssion issue.how to solve that issue can u plz tell

Comment: Easier to just do: `scp -r /path/to/files user@yourhost.com:/path/to/put/files/`

Comment: @wayenjoy no. it's a secret. just like your code.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i want to know the reason why it is happening

Comment: @wayenjoy: put `session_write_close()` into the script that the file is being uploaded to. that'll release the lock on the session file, allowing parallel requests.